# Integrate Ubuntu desktop to a Windows network

Tags: 10.04, active-directory

I currently have a Windows network (1 Windows 2008 R2 Server as the domain controller and 1 Windows Vista Client).

I have a Ubuntu 32 bit 10.04 client only (No Linux Server - so the client is not on a existing Linux network) and would like to integrate it into the Windows Network (AD) environment.

Please could you inform if this is possible and if yes, what are the steps to take to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Likewise Open.  [Likewise Open website here](http://www.beyondtrust.com/products/powerbroker-identity-services-open-edition/)

Download the free version. I normally extract the download into my home directory.  You can then open terminal, path to the LikewiseOpen directory and follow the below commands.

`# chmod  +x LikewiseOpen.sh`

```
# ./LikewiseOpen.sh
```

Follow the prompts.

Answer (score -2):

You can use software like Likewise or CentrifyDC.